# How make association on Rails 4 and Up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

After created the association on user new view and after created the user

the Location did not associated with the user, and in Console show

> irb(main):001:0> Location.last ArgumentError: No association found for
>   name `user'. Has it been defined yet?

I'm new on Rails 4 and instead of use attr_accessible  i placed the location_attributes on strong params
to see if solve, but did not solved.

someone have a hint to spare?

```
 def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email,:location_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :slug, 
                                   location_attributes:[:id, :location_id])
    end
```

**User Model**

```
belongs_to :location
```

**Location Model**

```
  has_many :users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, allow_destroy: true
```

**User new view**

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Your Name please', error: 'Name is mandatory' %>
  <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'user@domain.com' %>
    <%= f.input :password, hint: 'No special characters.' %>

    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, inline_label: 'Yes, remember me' %>



<%= f.simple_fields_for :location do |l| %>

      <%= l.input :country, label: "Country", collection: CountryStateSelect.countries_collection %>
<%= l.input :state, CountryStateSelect.state_options(label: "State / Province", form: f, field_names: { :country => :country, :state => :state } ) %>


      <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end
```

%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Location you define a `has_many :users` and then you `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, allow_destroy: true` (:users vs :user) so it's looking for a different association than the you created.

It also seems like you're creating a user form which will go through the User model to try and create locations but your models are set up such that you create users through a location (so your model doesn't match your view).

I believe what you're wanting to do would be to change your models to

### User Controller

```
def user_params
  ...location_attributes:[:id, :country, :state])
end
```

### User Model

```
belongs_to :location

accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, allow_destroy: true
```

### Location Model

```
has_many :users
```

and that *should* work. (I haven't done nested forms in years, but looking at the wiki for [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models) which you appear to be using, this should do it). If that doesn't work, it should at least be a step in the right direction.

Comment: thank you. almost there. you'right just left to know how to associate the has_model model on belonged model create view